What is Ctrl+Opt+Cmd+←/→ bound to on a fresh Sonoma 14.4?
I just got a new MacBook Pro and want to bind ^ Control+⌥ Option+⌘ Command+← / → to snapping windows to the left/right half of the screen (with Rectangle Pro). But I only hear an error ding when trying to assign it as well as using it anywhere else. I cannot find the shortcut in the Keyboard Shortcut section of the Settings nor does it seem to do anything.
What is this shortcut assigned to and how can I disable it? I don't want to install Shortcut Detective, as that needs Rosetta, and opensnoop needs SIP disabled.

Is this answer applicable Keyboard shortcuts for resizing windows

As a heads up, I am on ventura 13.4 22F66, on my machine Shortcut Detective and dtrace just don't work properly.

@AivarPaalberg Thank you for the suggestion. I have a tool to move windows, but I cannot assign the above mentioned shortcut, as it is apparently taken by something else, but I cannot find what has this shortcut.

It turned out that Rectangle had this shortcut already set and continued to have it occupied even when Rectangle was shut down, which I didn't expect. Layer 8 error, thank you to everyone that took a look.
